# Exact sequence for the sheaf of principal parts

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

> Let X be a smooth projective curve over a basis S of characteristic $ p$. Denote by $\mathscr P^1_{X/S}$ the sheaf of principal parts of degree $≤ 1$, namely the structural sheaf of the second order infinitesimal neighborhood $∆^{(2)}$ of the diagonal in $X ×_S X$ (EGA IV, sect $16$). The left $\mathscr O_X$-module structure is defined by the first projection and the right one by the second projection.Let 1 be the global section of $\mathscr P^1_{X/S}$ defined by the constant function with value 1 on $∆^{(2)}$ . The
>   restriction to the diagonal gives the exact sequence
>   $0 → ω_{X /S} → \mathscr P^1_{X/S} → \mathscr O_X → 0$ of left $\mathscr O_X$-modules.

I am having hard time understanding this paragraph, namely:

1. $ω_{X /S}$ is supposed to be the canonical line bundle of $X$. I found many references on this notion, for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_bundle)  and [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/line+bundle) but which applies in this context?
2. From definitions I found that $\mathscr P^1_{X/S} = ∆^*  \mathscr O_{X \times_S X}/\mathscr I^2$ for some sheaf of $\mathscr O_X-$ modules $\mathscr I$. But I don't understand the sentence with first and second projections
3. Finally I don't how we get the exact sequence.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you don’t like the EGA reference, there’s a very nice explanation of this concept in the book 3264 and All That by Eisenbud and Harris in the chapter on contact problems.

Comment: Thank you I will check this book

Comment: Actually I didn't find any reference to these questions in EGA IV